# Can we show that $(x_n)$ is relatively compact if and only if $(\langle x_n,\;\cdot\;\rangle)$ restricted to a closed ball is relatively compact?

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, compactness, equicontinuity, arzela-ascoli

Let $E$ be a Banach space, $\iota:E\to E''$ denote the canonical injection of $E$ into $E''$, i.e. $$\iota x:=\langle x,\;\cdot\;\rangle\;\;\;\text{for }x\in E,$$ $\sigma_c(E',E)$ denote the topology of compact convergence on $E$ and $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$.

> Are we able to show that $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is relatively compact if and only if there is a $r>0$ such that $(\left.\iota x_n\right|_{B^{E'}_r(0)})_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is relatively compact with respect to the topology of uniform convergence on $C(B^{E'}_r(0),\sigma_c(E',E))$?

The claim can be found in the proof of Linde's book *Probability in Banach Spaces - Stable and Infinitely Distributions*, Lemma 2.3.6:$^1$

[image: Lemma 2.3.6]

He also seems to conclude (most probably using the Arzelà-Ascoli theorem) that "$(\left.\iota x_n\right|_{B^{E'}_r(0)})_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is relatively compact with respect to the topology of uniform convergence on $C(B^{E'}_r(0),\sigma_c(E',E))$" follows from "$(\left.\iota x_n\right|_{B^{E'}_r(0)})_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is $\sigma_c(E',E)$-equicontinuous". But this is only true, if $(\left.\iota x_n\right|_{B^{E'}_r(0)})_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is pointwise bounded, which should be the case if (and only if) $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is bounded. Why is that the case?

---

$^1$ $V_\delta:=\{\varphi\in E':\left\|\varphi\right\|_{E'}\le\delta\}$ is endowed with the restriction of the topology $\sigma_c(E',E)$ and $\delta_x$ denotes the Dirac measure concentrated at $x$.

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but what is the canonical injection of a Banach space into its dual? What would this look like, for instance, if $E=L^1$?

Comment: @Jason Sorry, it should be $E''$, not $E'$.

Comment: I think $\sigma_{c}(E',E)$ should be $\sigma_{c}(E',E'')$ or something like that.  $ix$ is an element of $E''$ so it is a function on $E'$ and hence we should be discussing "compact convergence on $E'$" not on $E$.  (Same confusion with the notation $C(B^{E'}_{r}(0), \sigma_{c}(E',E))$.)

Comment: @Jason . For $x\in E$ and $y\in E'$ let $\iota x (y)=y(x).$ The Hahn-Banach Theorem implies $\|\iota x\|_{E''}=\|x\|_E.$

Comment: @PeterMorfe The weak* topology on $E'$ is usually denoted by $\sigma(E',E)$. It is the topology of pointwise convergence on $C(E,\mathbb K)$, $\mathbb K$ being the field over which $E$ is a vector space, restricted to the subspace $E'\subseteq C(E,\mathbb K)$. $\sigma_c(E',E)$ is simply meant to be the topology of compact convergence on $C(E,\mathbb K)$ restricted to $E'$.

Comment: @PeterMorfe In the context of the Arzelà-Ascoli theorem, we are considering a space $C(X,Y)$, where $X$ is a compact topological space and $Y$ is (for example) a metric space. Now, in the situation of the question, $X$ is a compact subset (endowed with the subspace topology) of $E'$ equipped with the topology $\sigma_c(E',E)$ and $Y=\mathbb K$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a set $E$, denote by $M(E)$ the set of all bounded functions on $E$ with the supremum norm topology.  We will consider $M(V_{\delta})$, where $V_{\delta} = \{\psi \in E' \, \mid \, \|\psi\| \leq \delta\}$.

**Claim:** $(x_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is relatively compact in $E$ if and only if, for some $\delta > 0$, $(i x_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is relatively compact in $M(V_{\delta})$.

The claim follows from the following equivalence: given any subsequence $(n_{j})_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ and any $\delta > 0$, $(x_{n_{j}})_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $E$ if and only if $(ix_{n_{j}})_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $M(V_{\delta})$.

Indeed, notice that, given $\delta > 0$, we have
\begin{align*}
\sup \left\{ |ix_{n_{j}}(\psi) - ix_{n_{k}}(\psi)| \, \mid \, \psi \in V_{\delta} \right\} &= \sup \left\{ |\psi(x_{n_{j}}) - \psi(x_{n_{k}})| \, \mid \, \psi \in V_{\delta} \right\} \\
&= \delta \|x_{n_{j}} - x_{n_{k}}\|.
\end{align*}
Thus, by the definition of Cauchy sequence, $(x_{n_{j}})_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ is Cauchy for the norm metric in $E$ if and only if it is Cauchy for the supremum norm metric in $M(V_{\delta})$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I'm still not able to deduce a solution to the problem in my question from it. I've provided the excerpt from Linde's book in my latest edit of the question. My main problem really is to show that $(\iota x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is pointwise bounded. This is clear to me, when $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is bounded (and so your proof doesn't help me, since you are assuming boundedness of $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$), but why do we know that $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is bounded?

Comment: Maybe a proof of the claim of the end of your question would shed some light. Can you provide a it?

Comment: What topology is on $C(V_{\delta})$?  Is it the topology of uniform convergence?

Comment: Yes, $C(V_\delta)$ is equipped with the supremum norm.

Comment: OK, now I think I see what your question is.  I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: I think your "if"-direction is actually the "only if"-direction and vice versa. And the $\tilde F$ on the right-hand side of the definition of $\tilde F$ should be $F$, right? Moreover, you should set $\tilde F(0):=0$.

Comment: "If" direction: $(x_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is relatively compact if $(ix_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is relatively compact.  "Only if" directional: $(x_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is relatively compact only if $(ix_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is relatively compact.  I agree that syntactically it is an annoying use of language.  (I corrected the definition of $\tilde{F}$.)

Comment: How exactly do you obtain the boundedness of $\tilde F$? If $\varphi\in E'\setminus\{0\}$, then $|\tilde F(\varphi)|=\lim_{k\to\infty}\left|\langle x_{j_k},\varphi\rangle\right|$, but how do you bound that without knowing that $\lim_{k\to\infty}\left\|x_{j_k}\right\|_E$ exists?

Comment: $F$ is a continuous function on $V_{\delta}$ and $V_{\delta}$ is compact.  Therefore, $F$ is bounded.  (Recall that $\tilde{F}$ being bounded in this case means there is a fixed $C > 0$ such that $|\tilde{F}(\psi)| \leq C \|\psi\|$ for all $\psi \in E'$.)

Comment: Yes, I know. Let's step back for a moment; ignoring the compactness thing. The only thing that matters is that $\left\|F\right\|_\infty=\sup_{\varphi\in V_\delta}|F(\varphi)|<\infty$, right? This allows us to conclude $|\tilde F(\varphi)|\le\frac{\left\|F\right\|_\infty}\delta\left\|\varphi\right\|_{E'}$, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.  A linear functional is uniquely determined by its values on any open ball centered at zero; and it's bounded if and only if the restriction to such a ball is bounded.

Comment: (a) Sure. Actually, I know all of this is quite elementary. What's confusing me (since it's somehow surprising to me) is that $\tilde F\in E''$, even though $f$ is only continuous with respect to the topology $\tau:=\left.\sigma_c(E',E)\right|_{V_\delta}$ on $V_\delta$, which is coarser than the subspace topology on $E'$ inherited from the norm topology on $E'$.

Comment: (b) I worry about one last thing: You wrote that $\iota(E)$ is a closed subset of $E''$, but I think that's not correct. $\iota$ is the canonical embedding of $E$ into its bidual $E''$. If $E$ is not complete, one usually constructs the *completion* of $E$ by $\overline{\iota(E)}$. So, I guess you are assuming that $E$ already is complete. Or did I miss something?

Comment: (a) It's linear and it satisfies the definition of bounded so it's continuous.  We are working with very special functions (linear ones) here so we have a lot of room.  (b) You say in your post that $E$ is a Banach space, which is nothing other than a *complete* normed vector space.

Comment: (Arguably, the question is overdetermined.  You could just as well say that $(x_{n})$ is relatively compact in $E$ if and only if $(ix_{n})$ is relatively compact in $M(V_{\delta})$ for some $\delta > 0$, where $M(V_{\delta})$ is the space of bounded functions on $V_{\delta}$ with the supremum norm topology.  The topology of $V_{\delta}$ is irrelevant.)

Comment: Got it now. I've accepted your answer, but please take a look at the [answer I've provided below](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4019557/47771) for clarity and let me know whether you agree or not.

Comment: Would still be interested in whether you agree or not.

Answer (score 0):

[Peter Morfe](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/711689/peter-morfe)'s [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4019557/47771) answered my question, which is why I've accepted it. However, since the whole stuff with the $\sigma_c(E',E)$-topology on $E'$ confused me and it turned out that everything is way more elementary than I thought, I will reformulate the result, which can be proved in the way Peter described in his answer.

Let

- $\mathbb F=\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb F=\mathbb C$;
- $X$ be a normed $\mathbb F$-vector space;
- $\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle$ denote the canonical duality pairing between $X$ and $X'$;
- $\iota$ denote the canonical embedding of $X$ into $X''$, i.e. $$\iota:X\to X''\;,\;\;\;x\mapsto\langle x,\;\cdot\;\rangle;$$
- $V_r:=\overline B^{X'}_r(0)$ for $r>0$.

Remember that if $V$ is any set, then $$B(V):=\left\{f:V\to\mathbb F\mid\left\|f\right\|_\infty<\infty\right\}$$ equipped with $\left\|\;\cdot\;\right\|_\infty$ is a $\mathbb F$-Banach space.

> **Proposition**: Let $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq X$ and $$f_n:=\iota(x_n)\;\;\;\text{for }n\in\mathbb N.$$
>
> 1. If $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is relatively compact, then $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is relatively compact in $\iota(X)$. In particular, $\left(\left.f_n\right|_{V_r}\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is relatively compact in $B(V_r)$ for *all* $r>0$.
> 2. If $X$ is complete and $\left(\left.f_n\right|_{V_r}\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is relatively compact in $B(V_r)$ for *some* $r>0$, then $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is relatively compact.

Now the result asked for in the question is a simple corollary: If $r>0$ and $\tau$ is any compact topology on $V_r$, then $$C(V_r,\tau):=\left\{f:V_r\to\mathbb F\mid f\text{ is }\tau\text{-continuous}\right\}$$ is a *closed* subspace of $B(V_r)$. Thus, if $\iota(X)\subseteq C(V_r,\tau)$, then $\left(\left.f_n\right|_{V_r}\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ being relatively compact in $B(V_r)$ implies that $\left(\left.f_n\right|_{V_r}\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is relatively compact in $C(V_r,\tau)$.

Comment: Looks good to me!

Comment: @PeterMorfe Thank you for the review.